# Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found:

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, tools.jar

When compiling a project in Eclipse, I get below error:

> Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found:

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Di you try to run the build on command line?

Comment: yes..its working fine in command line.

Comment: One more place to check is the JRE tab on the Maven Build Run Configuration window.

Comment: Even i faced this issue. It was a eclipse config problem related to JRE. http://sudotutorials.com/java/870/tools-jar-not-found-cprogram-filesjavajre7-libtools-jar/

Answer (score 42, accepted):

<kbd>Goto Windows</kbd> -> <kbd>Preferences</kbd>

<kbd>Java</kbd> -> <kbd>Installed JREs</kbd> –> <kbd>Execution Environment</kbd>

<kbd>JavaSE1.x</kbd> -> <kbd>JDE 1.x</kbd>

---

If you don’t have the `JDK` in the Installed `JRE`, then

Select the Installed `JRE` and Add the `JDK` installed path

---

Let's try to configure your run configurations to clean install

[image]

Click on the small black arrow and then Run Configurations

After, you just put clean install in your Maven goal, like this :

[image]

And then, try to run your compilation, and we will see what happens... :)

Comment: Yes I DId. Now it shoes this error.Posted in the Question

Comment: All the build runs fine in the command prompt, But not sure exactly the problem with eclipse.

Comment: OK you should configure your run configurations if the problem change to this :)

Your maven goal should be something like : clean install

Comment: I was showing a bunch of errors yesterday.An internal error occurred during: "Loading descriptor for xxx.".
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.FeatureNotFoundException: Feature 'taglib' not found. (platform:/resource/xxx/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml, 226, 11). This was one of the errors yesterday

Comment: This was an other one..Could not get the value for parameter encoding for plugin execution default-resources
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 (

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /xxx/ and also has a unhandled event loop exception->plugin> org.eclipse.ui in the error log... :|

Comment: O.o OK maybe you have a proxy or something, and your maven don't succeed to download packages... :/ 

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: I dont have a settings.xml file under my repository!!!

Answer (score 23):

You need to put the right Java Build path for your project.

In Eclipse:

--> Right click the project name - Properties (keyboard shortcut: [Alt] + [Enter] ) 
--> Libraries
--> Change the JRE7 to JDK7.

And I think the problem will be solved that way ;)

Comment: Dont see a libraries section when hit alt+enter!!!

Comment: Ok, so : right-click on your project, and then, properties

Comment: I found the java build path Valentin, but It shows all the project jar files. I did change the path to JDk in the preferences->java->installed jre->jdk...But its not helping

Comment: I had to create a JAVA_HOME variable within eclipse (go to preferences -> java -> build path -> class path variable) and point this to JDK7 - it started to work

Comment: @JavaTec Better to add Windows -> Preferences....