# Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\..\lib\tools.jar ->

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar

I am having a strange issue. I am using `maven 3.2`, `java 1.6`  and `jboss 5.1`.
I am using all these old version because I have some system requirement.
I am working on web application.
I am getting an error
`Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\..\lib\tools.jar ->`

imperviously it was working fine. When I made some changes in code and when I did this from that time I am getting This error.

[image]

1. I tried updating maven forcefully.
2. I tried maven install from eclipse.
3. Even I downloaded the missing jar and put into `C:\Program
   Files\Java\jre6\..\lib\` this path.

and many more still I am getting this error. please help me.

Comment: Hi, see answers in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185634/maven-build-failed-fatal-error-compiling-tools-jar-not-found

Answer (score 1):

I think your eclipse is pointed to JRE not JDK. Can you point it to JDK and check?

Answer (score 1):

Mistake you did is ---
Your build path is pointing to the wrong JRE directory/folder. So, you have to change the build path to JRE folder(which is inside the JDK folder) rather not the JRE folder that's available outside the JDK.

Eclipse > Select Windows > properties > Java > Installed JREs

• Select the "jreX" under the Installed JREs list > Select "Edit" or double click

• Your JRE home directory location may be pointing to something like

JRE home: C:..\Java\jre1.x --- (which is wrong)

• Point to the right directory as follows:

JRE home: C:..\java\jdk1.x\jre --- (this is right)

• Finish.

Clean your project and compile it. It should work fine :)