# ant extgen not working in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to add a custom extension in Hybris using the following commands:

```
1) E:\twork\hybriszip\hybris\bin\platform>setantenv.bat
2) E:\twork\hybriszip\hybris\bin\platform>ant modulegen
3) E:\twork\hybriszip\hybris\bin\platform>ant extgen
```

The above first two commands are working properly but the third command isn't working, please check this screenshot:

[image: this screenshot].

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185634/fatal-error-compiling-tools-jar-not-found

Comment: Looks like you have an issue on the config/localextensions.xml file, as the error reports, there are some problems there with the extension tag, I would double check that file and make sure it's valid

Answer (score 0):

Check your localextensions.xml file. Probably there is an error, a tag is not closed properly.